# repeatedly getting uncaught exception in firebug

Tags: django, firebug

my project suddenly was started to throwing exception in firebug,I've not added any new thing,I'm confused,the error:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMNSHTMLTextAreaElement.selectionStart]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://codeblogging.net/static/js/plugins.js ::  :: line 99"  data: no]
>   Line 0

I've just used `django-tinymce` in my project,but there was no problem until now,I removed the refrences to `tinymce.js` and `tinymce-setup.js`,but no difference!I really don't know what has happend!!

Comment: Error is in WMD Editor (`http://codeblogging.net/static/js/plugins.js`). Look for `selectionStart` there

Comment: Sorry,I don't know whats WMD,what do U mean with selectionStart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally updated firefox to 12 version and updated firebug to a compatible version,too.